# Why does this generic method require T to have a public, parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public void Getrecords(ref IList iList,T dataItem) 
{ 
  iList = Populate.GetList<dataItem>() // GetListis defined as GetList<T>
}
```

dataItem can be my order object or user object which will be decided at run time.The above does not work as it gives me this error
The type 'T' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type

Comment: You're question is very vague and hard to understand... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why is this guy getting voted down for simply asking a question?

Comment: Can you clarify what dataItem does here? It can't be used as the generic type argument (T can). So what does it do?

Comment: Re the answer (on my post) - so does either of the two scenarios I posted help?

Answer (score 7):

```
public void GetRecords<T>(ref IList<T> iList, T dataitem)
{
}
```

What more are you looking for?

**To Revised question:**

```
 iList = Populate.GetList<dataItem>()
```

"dataitem" is a variable.  You want to specify a type there:

```
 iList = Populate.GetList<T>()
```

> The type 'T' must have a public
>   parameterless constructor in order to
>   use it as parameter 'T' in the generic
>   type GetList:new()

This is saying that when you defined Populate.GetList(), you declared it like this:

```
IList<T> GetList<T>() where T: new() 
{...}
```

That tells the compiler that GetList can only use types that have a public parameterless constructor.  You use T to create a GetList method  in GetRecords (T refers to different types here), you have to put the same limitation on it:

```
public void GetRecords<T>(ref IList<T> iList, T dataitem) where T: new() 
{
   iList = Populate.GetList<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your revised question passes in dataItem as an object of type T and then tries to use it as a type argument to GetList().  Perhaps you pass dataItem in only as a way to specify T?

If so, the you may want something like so:

```
public IList<T> GetRecords<T>() {
  return Populate.GetList<T>();
}
```

Then you call that like so:

```
IList<int> result = GetRecords<int>();
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this The type 'T' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type

GetList<T>:new()

Comment: If you need to be able to create a new one, specify T: object

Comment: Or, you can use default(T) to create a new instance as well.

Comment: where T : new() is what the compiler wants

Comment: I thought this was what he wanted for a while, too, and then I realized he probably already has an object of some type that he wants to use to determine the type parameter to the method.  Even so, this is still probably the right way to go.  Just use MyDataItem.GetType() for the type parameter.

Comment: Hmm... except you can't do that.

Comment: to my knowledge, c# generics are executed as a compiler trick to achieve the static typing.  If jon b truly needs run-time generic typing, perhaps the DLR will help.

Comment: @Joel - yes you can; via MakeGenericMethod (see pots)

Comment: @David - no, generics are a core part of the CLR v2; the compiler doesn't do any real tricks here; in fact, generics in C# follow static typing rules (everything done in C# < 4.0 is static typed)

Answer (score 4):

The issue with demanding a public, parameterless constructor can only be because Populate.GetList demands it - i.e. has the "T : new()" constraint. To fix this, simply add the same constraint to your method.

Actually, I doubt that `ref` is a good strategy here. At a push, `out` might do (since you don't read the value), but a far simpler (and more expected) option is a return value:

```
public IList<T> GetRecords<T>(T dataItem) where T : new()
{  // MG: what does dataItem do here???
  return Populate.GetList<T>();
}
```

Of course, at that point, the caller might as well just call `Populate.GetList` directly!

I suspect you can remove dataItem too... but it isn't entirely clear from the question.

If you don't intend it to be generic (and dataItem is the template object), then you can do this via `MakeGenericMethod`:

```
public static IList GetRecords(object dataItem) 
{
    Type type = dataItem.GetType();
    return (IList) typeof(Populate).GetMethod("GetList")
        .MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null,null);
}
```

Comment: MG: If i have a order object then the list will be collection of order objects and it helps me avoid building my own strongly typed collection inheriting from collection base and looping through a dataset and building the collection so I can pass the custom collection around instead of a dataset

Answer (score -1):

You can use Generic with  < T > that will accept the type in runtime like you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
Getrecords<T> ...
```

This should have any more detailed information that you need. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(VS.80).aspx